# log4net xml logs deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, logging, log4net

I have a log4net UdpAppender used to log xml data using XmlLayout (see [this page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.XmlLayout.html) for documentation):

`<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
      <remoteAddress value="224.1.2.3"/>
      <remotePort value="8080"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayout" />
    </appender>`

What I obtain (as expected) from a `log.Warn("TEST DEBUG");` call is:

```
<log4net:event logger="multicast_test" timestamp="2014-02-11T15:32:24.5343376+01
:00" level="WARN" thread="10" domain="multicast_test.vshost.exe" username="DOMAIN\user"><log4net:message>TEST DEBUG</log4net:message><log4net:properties><l
og4net:data name="log4net:Identity" value="" /><log4net:data name="log4net:UserN
ame" value="DOMAIN\user" /><log4net:data name="log4net:HostName" value="MACHINE" /></log4net:properties></log4net:event>
```

I'd like to deserialize logs in some way but unfortunately I can't find any useful information in log4net sdk documentation / google search.

Comment: Serialization is provided automatically by log4net architecture. I'd like to **deserialize** xml log data.

Comment: Not sure whether this helps but there is a project at [https://log2console.codeplex.com](https://log2console.codeplex.com/) which does something similar in that it is de-serializing or parsing the xml in Log4jXmlFormat (as opposed to XmlLayout)

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Meanwhile I'm going on the manual XML deserialization way...